# Conquest narrows the peaceful fields

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

I can't figure out the phrase «conquest narrows the peaceful fields» from the poem by Edna St. Vincent Millay. What does it means?

Comment: Poets are a strange species. We don't answer questions such as interpretation of their poems.

Comment: Sorry, but [Criticism, discussion, and analysis of English literature](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

Narrows is likely being used in the sense of shrinks--it's an anti-war poem, so the observation is being made in that context (arrows shrink the peaceful fields in wartime). She was making a rhyme with arrows, so there is the chance she wanted a secondary meaning of arrows/narrow the soldier's life--whenever there is a rhyme in place within a poem, you should check to see the relation of the words and how they are being employed within the framework of the poem.

> Make bright the arrows
>
> Gather the shields:
>
> Conquest narrows
>
> The peaceful fields.
>
> Stock well the quiver
>
> With arrows bright:
>
> The bowman feared
>
> Need never fight.
>
> Make bright the arrows,
>
> O peaceful and wise!
>
> Gather the shields
>
> Against surprise.